# How to type two statements side by side with an iff between them

Tags: math-mode

Hello im wondering if there is a way of typesetting two blocks of text with equations in side by side with an iff between them? (as shown by the image, sorry for the bad picture quality!)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equations can be grouped with `gathered` or `aligned` inside displayed equations
(package `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{gathered}
    T[\phi_i] \rightarrow T[\phi]\\
    \text{as } i \rightarrow \infty
  \end{gathered}
  \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  \begin{gathered}
    T[\vartheta] \text{ in somewhere}\\
    \forall \vartheta \in \mathcal{D}_0(\mathcal{U})
    \text{ bounded on } \mathcal{D}_0(\mathcal{U})
  \end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

Two out of countless possibilities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[
 \left.\begin{array}{rcl}
 T[\phi_i] & \to& T[\phi]\\
 \text{as}~i& \to & \infty
 \end{array}\right\}
 \Longleftrightarrow
 \left\{\begin{array}{l}
 \text{$T$ is bounded}\\
 \forall\vartheta\in\mathscr{D}_0(U)~\text{bounded on}~\mathscr{D}_0(U)
 \end{array}\right.
\]
or
\[
 T[\phi_i] \xrightarrow{i\to\infty} T[\phi]\quad
 \Longleftrightarrow
 \begin{cases}
 \text{$T$ is bounded}\\
 \forall\vartheta\in\mathscr{D}_0(U)~\text{bounded on}~\mathscr{D}_0(U)
 \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `aligned` to have more control over the alignment between the two lines. In the left half, we have two `\rightarrow`s which can be aligned; in the right half, we may also have two `\in`s which can be aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    T[\phi_i]    & \rightarrow T[\phi]\\
    \text{as } i & \rightarrow \infty
  \end{aligned}
  \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
  \begin{aligned}
    &T[\vartheta] \text{ in somewhere}\\
    &\forall\vartheta\in\mathcal{D}_0(\mathcal{U}) \text{ bounded on } \mathcal{D}_0(\mathcal{U})
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]